# Basic ideas behind design of different topologies of DC-DC converter

Tags: switches, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, buck-boost

I can analyse most of the DC-DC converter circuits that are mostly given in textbooks.

But how these complex topologies are designed for the first time i.e. what are the basic ideas that lead to design of different topologies?

For more context- an example -

In a buck converter we have a clear idea before designing the circuit

1. Using switch we can reduce the average voltage across load.
2. Using L-C filter we can minimize the voltage and current ripples without affecting average voltage across load.

To me, except buck converter, most of the converter circuits looks very random but somehow works.

Although this question seems very general but one example of any complex topology **(boost or buck-boost or non isolated SEPIC or H bridge converter)** is enough for this question.

Due to presence lot of variables  (i.e switches, inductors, capacitors) and specially switches which introduces non linearity as well as discontinuity,  is there still a way to reduce some variables (by using some basic ideas) or it all boils down to hit and trial or there were some algorithm that were used for designing different topologies of converter?

Comment: Think of problems associated with a simple buck converter: 1) input current ripple 2) switching losses due to hard commutation 3) lack of in-out isolation 4) only steps voltage down. Now how would you solve these? you may arrive at some of the more complex converters..

Comment: @tobalt , thanks for the feedback But these consideration work when you already know how the circuit looks like and we have to find L or C , but my question was like  how on Earth someone can think of H- bridge converter (or any other converters) for the first time ?

Comment: H bridge converter is rather obvious. You have a transformer so you need to feed it AC. Hoe do you do this? Either a centre tapped transformer and a double ended drive or a h bridge. Not too far removed from a valve audio amplifier.

Comment: _"To me, except buck converter, most of the converter circuits looks very random"_ - to you they do, but to those of us who understand how inductors work they are obvious.

Comment: Wouldn't the real question be: How can I transform the energy at my disposal into another with the least possible loss?

Comment: @Antonio51 , yes (+ using completely New switching circuits )